# Como dibujar la figura seleccionada de la lista con la medida del radio o lado que introduce el usuario en Python con Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

Necesito hacer un programa en donde el usuario introduzca el valor que desea que tenga el radio o lado de la figura y seguidamente escoja una primera figura de las posibles de una lista para que esta sea dibujada con el valor anteriormente introducido y luego una segunda figura. Para esto decidí usar tkinter y turtle en python.

El o los problemas son que cuando quiero guardar el valor en una variable, me sale este error: Entry.get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Además, el código que uso para que se active la función `select` y dibuje el círculo, en este caso, cuando se selecciona dicha opción,  `ComboboxSelected` no parece que active nada. No sé si debo poner la opción de otra manera dentro de la función  En este caso, importé turtle para el dibujo de las figuras, ya que me parecía menos complejo.

Evidentemente aún falta programar las demás figuras y la otra lista para la segunda figura, pero quiero que funcione antes de continuar. Agradecería todos los consejos posibles.
Aquí está mi código:

```
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

inicio = Tk()
inicio.geometry("600x500")
inicio.title("Dibujos de figuras")

texto = Entry(inicio, font = "Helvetica 15")
texto.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relwidth=1, relheight=0.05)
m = None

radiolado = Label(inicio, text = "Radio o lado en cm")
radiolado.place(relx=0, rely=0.05)

def guardar_Valor():
    global m
    valor = Entry.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    m = valor

def select(event):
        if lista_1.get() == "Círculo":
            c = Turtle()
            c.circle(m)

figura_1 = Label(inicio, text = "Figura 1")
figura_1.place(relx=0.43,rely=0.25)

figura_2 = Label(inicio, text = "Figura 2")
figura_2.place(relx=0.43,rely=0.6)

lista_1 = ttk.Combobox(inicio, state="readonly",values=["Círculo", "Cuadrado", "Triángulo", "Pentágono", "Hexágono"])
lista_1.current(0)
lista_1.place(relx= 0.35,rely=0.3)
lista_1.bind("«ComboboxSelected»", select)

Boton1= Button(inicio, text = "Guardar", command = guardar_Valor)
Boton1.place(relx= 0.42,rely=0.18)


lista_2 = ttk.Combobox(inicio, state="readonly",values=["Círculo", "Cuadrado", "Triángulo", "Pentágono", "Hexágono"])
lista_2.current(1)
lista_2.place(relx= 0.35,rely=0.7)

    

inicio.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu código están los siguientes problemas:

- `Entry.get(1.0, "end-1c")` simplemente no tiene sentido. Entry es el objeto que usas para crear el widget Entry, NO el entry que usas. Además, mirando los argumentos, estás tratando al entry como el widget Text. Así no funciona el obtener el valor de un entry. La forma correcta es `texto.get()`
- En esta linea `lista_1.bind("«ComboboxSelected»", select)` Las cadenas `<<` y `>>` NO son lo mismo que los caracteres `«` y `«`. Empezando por que el primer caso tiene 2 caracteres y el segundo uno. La forma correcta es `lista_1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", select)`
- `texto.get()` te devolverá una cadena, no un numero. Eso es un valor no valido para turtle. Tendrás que convertir esto a entero con la función int. `int(texto.get())`. Ojo, sin validar que el contenido del entry efectivamente se pueda convertir a entero, ocurrirá un error cuando ingreses algo no numerico como aaa1.

###### Código corregido

```
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

inicio = Tk()
inicio.geometry("600x500")
inicio.title("Dibujos de figuras")

texto = Entry(inicio, font = "Helvetica 15")
texto.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relwidth=1, relheight=0.05)
m = None

radiolado = Label(inicio, text = "Radio o lado en cm")
radiolado.place(relx=0, rely=0.05)

def guardar_Valor():
    global m
    valor = int(texto.get())
    m = valor

def select(event):
        if lista_1.get() == "Círculo":
            c = Turtle()
            c.circle(m)

figura_1 = Label(inicio, text = "Figura 1")
figura_1.place(relx=0.43,rely=0.25)

figura_2 = Label(inicio, text = "Figura 2")
figura_2.place(relx=0.43,rely=0.6)

lista_1 = ttk.Combobox(inicio, state="readonly",values=["Círculo", "Cuadrado", "Triángulo", "Pentágono", "Hexágono"])
lista_1.current(0)
lista_1.place(relx= 0.35,rely=0.3)
lista_1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", select)

Boton1= Button(inicio, text = "Guardar", command = guardar_Valor)
Boton1.place(relx= 0.42,rely=0.18)


lista_2 = ttk.Combobox(inicio, state="readonly",values=["Círculo", "Cuadrado", "Triángulo", "Pentágono", "Hexágono"])
lista_2.current(1)
lista_2.place(relx= 0.35,rely=0.7)

    

inicio.mainloop()
```